# run time error when deleting values in drop down list cells

Tags: excel

I have several columns in this excel sheet with 2 being drop down lists.

Root cause column is a drop down
Sub root cause is a dependent drop down list (to the value selected in root cause)

While testing the excel, I found if I select the values in root cause/sub root cause and hit delete I get a run time error.
I want to be able to clear the values like this as a user may want to mass select rows and clear.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Column = 9 Then
        If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
   
  If Target.Column = 9 Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
          Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
  End If
  
   
  Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: please add the code as text and not a photo.  We cannot copy paste a photo.

Comment: But the answer is that you cannot equate multiple cells with `""` you will need to loop the Target cells instead of trying to do all at once.

Comment: so the code works fine. I only have this issue if deleting . Would not having a loop cause that to occur only on delete? I pasted the code in the post.

Comment: You cannot do something like: `Range("A1:A4").Value = ""` you will get an error.  so you must loop that range and compare each cell.  If you delete only one cell it should work.  But when deleting many at once `Target` is a multi cell range and therefore you need to loop it and make sure you are looking at the correct column.

Comment: could you suggest how to write this. I am a novice here and I am not understanding how to loop this code.                                                                                                                         
                     FYI I am seeing this line of the code is what is causing the problem. so I removed this line to play with it and added something else for this target and the run time didnt occur.  But if I remove this I lose the functionality I want.                                                         If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then

Comment: The is the first error, but there will be others.  Add a `For Each` loop around the whole so you are always looking in one cell at a time.